# Transfering the audio file name to html via javascript based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

    function quesfl(qsvalue) { 
    document.getElementById("bebo1").innerHTML= qsvalue + ".wav";
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="qno" value="02" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">2
<input type="radio" name="qno" value="03" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">3
<input type="radio" name="qno" value="04" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">4

<center><audio controls>
<source id = 'bebo1' src= 'bebo1' type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio></center><br>


</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to play a particular audiofile by clicking the corresponding radio buttons. For that I wanted a variable 'bebo1' to get refered at the html audio part for play. This part is not working. The audio files are also available. Please help.

Comment: use something like jQuery to modify the `src` of the audio html tag. `getElementById` will return nothing, you do not have any HTML tag with an `id='bebo1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update the src of source
2. Load & play audio with load() & play()

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function quesfl(qsvalue) { 
        var audio1= document.getElementById("audio1");
        document.getElementById("bebo1").src = qsvalue + ".wav";
        audio1.load();
        audio1.play();
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="radio" name="qno" value="02" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">2
    <input type="radio" name="qno" value="03" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">3
    <input type="radio" name="qno" value="04" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">4

    <center><audio controls id="audio1">
    <source id="bebo1" type="audio/wav">
    Your browser does not support this audio format.
    </audio></center><br>
    </body>
</html>
```